# hook to click event inside embedded youtube player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api

I want to run a function called `stopSlide` whenever someone clicks the 'play' button on an embedded youtube video. Or even getting the function to run when they click *anywhere* inside the embedded video would work fine for me right now.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a YouTube JavaScript API that provides event callbacks.

There is, unfortunately, no way to directly detect a click event (at least I am not aware of any). You can, however, detect changes in the player state for which you can use [`onStateChange`](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Events).

First, you will need to enable the JS API in the player by embedding it by using a special URL:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3&enablejsapi=1
```

Then you need to create an event handler function:

```
function player_state_changed(state) {
  /* This event is fired whenever the player's state changes.
     Possible values are:
     - unstarted (-1)
     - ended (0)
     - playing (1)
     - paused (2) 
     - buffering (3)
     - video cued (5). 
     When the SWF is first loaded it will broadcast an unstarted (-1) event.
     When the video is cued and ready to play it will broadcast a video cued event (5).
  */

  if (state == 1 || state == 2) {
    alert('the "play" button *might* have been clicked');
  }

}
```

Lastly, you need to make sure that the handler gets called whenever the state of the movie changes:

```
document.getElementById('MY-PLAYER-ID').addEventListener('onStateChange', 'player_state_changed');
```

Comment: Since I'm a noob at this: what code would I put in my js file (or html) to utilize that event?

Comment: I've extended my answer, hope it will be more helpful now.

Comment: what do you mean by "MY-PLAYER-ID" here?

Comment: @Serge: the ID of your player element

Comment: what do you mean by "player element": the <iframe> id?

Comment: This Q/A is very old. There's probably a new API these days.

Answer (score 9):

Might be helpful ... edit according to your requirement 
http://jsfiddle.net/masiha/4mEDR/

Comment: Great fiddle. Very key detail which Masiha does not mention... the string `'player'` in the line `new YT.Player('player', ...` is a reference to the ID of the iFrame that embeds the YouTube video.

Comment: This is a very concise example - liked it. Thanks for sharing the link :)

Comment: it doesn't alert for me. why?

Answer (score 1):

i tried using the suggestions above but didnt succeed.
it can't handle timer slider.
please see Google example for automatic slider, they used a popup for the video.
[google slider with embedded video](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/helloworld/index.html)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If I get it right, this video helped? If so, would you please add an excerpt of that information here? That way your answer will remain useful if the link dies.

Comment: Can you use the name's of the people whose suggestions didn't work? Unfortunately, on this site one can sort the answers in many different manners and hence "above" has no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Upto my knowledge you can't detect a click inside a iframe,or you can't trigger any click event inside the iframe 
My solution is place a button inside the Iframe set it's properties as transparent(opacity) inside that button you can call your click function using playmethod and pause method you can enable autoplay

Answer (score 0):

You need to just register an event listener on the player to call your `stopSlide` function. The following line of code should do it for you (first you have to replace the two "*strings*" with the appropriate values - the ID of the embedded player, and the name of the function that you want to call. eg: "stopSlide"):

```
document.getElementById("_idOfEmbeddedPlayerElement_").addEventListener("onStateChange", "_nameOfFunctionToCall_");`
```

Comment: This would trigger the callback function on every event, such as cue, buffer, play, pause, stop, end.

Comment: what exactly "id of the embedded player" should we search? the <iframe> id or embedded id of the youtube video?